# How do I superimpose a regression line in a barplot in R?

Tags: r

So I want to superimpose a regression line in a barplot in R. Similar to the attached image by Rosindell et al. 2011. However, when I try to do this with my data the line does not stretch the entire length of the barplot.

For a reproducible example, I made a dummy code:

```
x = 20:1 
y = 1:20

barplot(x, y, space = 0)
lines(x, y, col = 'red')
```

How do I get the lines to transverse the entire stretch of the barplot bins?

PS: the line does not need to be non-linear. I just want to superimpose a straight line on the barplot

Thank you.

[image: Rindell et al. 2011]
[image: My sample plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general solution could be to rely on the x-values that are generated by `barplot()`. This way, you can deal with scenarios where you only have counts (rather than x and y values). I am referring to a variable like this one, where your "x" is categorical (precisely, x-axis values correspond to the names of y).

```
p.x <- c(8,12,14,9,5,3,2)
x <- sample(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"), 
            prob = p.x/sum(p.x),
            replace = TRUE, 
            size = 200)
y <- table(x)
y
#  A  B  C  D  E  F  G 
# 27 52 46 36 21 11  7
```

When you use `barplot()`, you can collect the x-positions of the bars in a variable (`plot.dim` in this case) and use to guide your line

```
plot.dim <- barplot(y)
lines(plot.dim, y, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

The result
[image]

Now, back to your data. Even if you have both x and y, in a barplot you are displaying only your y variable, while x is used for the labels of y.

```
x <- 20:1 
y <- as.integer(22 - 1 * sample(seq(0.7, 1.3, length.out = length(x))) * x)

names(y) <- x
y <- y[order(as.numeric(names(y)))]
```

Let's plot your y values again. Collect the barplot positions in the xpos variable.

```
xpos <- barplot(y, las = 2)
```

Note that the first bar (x=1) is not positioned at 1. Similarly, the last bar is positioned at 23.5 (and not 20).

```
xpos[1]
# x=1 is indeed at 0.7
xpos[length(xpos)]
# x=20 is indeed at 23.5
```

Do your regression (for example, use `lm()`). Compute the predicted y values at the first and the last x (y labels).

```
lm.fit <- lm(y~as.numeric(names(y)))
y.init <- lm.fit$coefficients[2] * as.numeric(names(y))[1] + lm.fit$coefficients[1]
y.end <- lm.fit$coefficients[2] * as.numeric(names(y))[(length(y))] + lm.fit$coefficients[1]
```

You can now over-pose a line using `segments()`, but remember to set your x-values according to what stored in `xpos`.

```
segments(xpos[1], y.init, xpos[length(xpos)], y.end, lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this Dr. Fantini. I tried this on my data, and it worked. However, is there a way to make the line straight (i.e. it does not bounce around the center for the bins). I want to make a linear regression line transverse the barplot in my data; hence, it would be good if the line is straight.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your question. Sure you can overly the regression. Just make sure to use the x-values returned by the barplot() function.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the help page `?barplot`: the second argument is `width - optional vector of bar widths`, not the `y` coordinate. The following code does what you want, but I don't believe it's a general purpose solution.

```
barplot(y[x], space = 0)
lines(x, y, col = 'red')
```

[image]

**Edit:**
A probably better way would be to use the return value of `barplot`.

```
bp <- barplot(y[x], space = 0)
lines(c(bp), y[x], col = 'red')
```